# Display icon in ActionBar with drawables in the Spinner dropdown

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-drawable

I'm trying to piece together several features at once and having a problem, but I'm close. I need a share icon in my ActionBar that when clicked, shows a Spinner dropdown menu with a list of 3 icons (no text). I am not using a custom adapter, because it seemed like I didn't need it (correct me if I'm wrong), so I'm trying to use some of the default code of the Spinner to create it. I was able to get the Spinner in the ActionBar, but it is showing only the name of the resource file array I am using, and not the drawable itself. Plus, the icon is not showing. I've been on this for 2 days and can't find help from other sources. They are all different from my situation. How do I get the ActionBar icon to show and for the Spinner drawables to show? Thanks.

**Here, the spinner shows the top of the list title instead of the share icon**

[image]

**Here, the spinner dropdown list is made up of the drawable name, not the drawable itself**

[image]

**PhotoViewerActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);

        Spinner shareSpinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_social_share).getActionView();

        spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this, R.array.icons,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        shareSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        shareSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Makes the UP caret go back to the previous fragment MakeCuteHome
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_social_share:


                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**spinner_array.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/ic_facebook</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_twitter</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_sms</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

**menu_share.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Share, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_social_share"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_social_share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"/>

</menu>
```

**action_share.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/share_spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Create Custom raw layout file with image which can display your icons. and pass that with your adapter.

Comment: Thanks, should I create a new directory for `raw` files? I've not made one before. In a nutshell, can you say why this is better?

Comment: Need to make custom layout file in which textView display your image name and your icon is in ImageView and inflate that layout file to adapter class

Comment: Thanks @Piyush, although as I said, I don't want text, I only want the image (drawable). So if I make an ImageView, then that means I need to make a custom adapter, correct? Because the ImageView will act as a row of the Spinner xml. I was hoping to avoid custom adapter, unless there is not other way.

Comment: you are using default raw file that supports only text. if you want to support your custom view, you have to create custom raw. you can modify whenever you want and however you want.

Comment: @Pragnesh... oh, I didn't realize I was already using a raw file. Online it said stuff about you need InputStream... was not sounding easy. The thing is, I need an array of images. I tried just making an `Integer[ ]` array in my activity, but then putting the array in the adapter code did not work, it expected only one `int`, not the whole array of them. Do you know of an example to make the file custom for images? Because that is just showing the array, which I will need an array (but of images, not text). Sorry, I hope that makes sense. I just can't picture what the solution will look like.

Comment: Lots of examples are available online, you just need to search about it.

Comment: Okay I will, but search for what exactly? I've been searching all kinds of stuff for Spinner, drawable in Spinner, Spinner in ActionBar. Only stuff out there is a custom adapter, which I was not having luck with so far. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: custom spinner raw for android

Comment: take any example of custom spinner and modify raw file. that's damn easy girl. :)

Comment: Actually it's not. I'm trying to use so many different ones, but it's the part of hooking up the Spinner to the icon in the ActionBar that is tripping me up. Plus, no tutorial I am finding is calling it a "raw" file. If you just mean create a custom `xml`, yes, I did do that. But I find lots of Spinner tutorials for images, that's not hard, but it's putting the Spinner into `onCreateOptionsMenu` that is not working. I might try to rewrite a new question and focus on just that. Thanks.